# Bootstrap Fileinput + reCaptcha

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, file-io, disabled-control

I'm using Bootstrap Fileinput and it works perfectly. My problem is that I want to use Google reCaptcha to avoid bad attitudes, you know.

What I don't know is how I could disable the file upload until the user solves the reCaptcha. Until then, I would like to disable the "upload" button or something similar.

Any idea?

Thanks!

EDIT: I verify the reCaptcha on the server side and return a response text to the javascript

Comment: The success of the reCAPTCHA should always be verified server side as well...

Comment: Yes, I verify it on the server side using ajax and get the response on the JS